# Return subset of attribute value when reading item

Tags: amazon-web-services, subset, dynamodb-queries

My dynamodb table is storing multiple attributes on each item, one of which being an array with a relatively large amount of entries. Whenever I read an item of my table, I really only need a certain subset of that array, so it's a waste of data throughput to query the entire thing.

Example: A good analogy would be stock price history; each entry in my table represents a certain stock, and the array attribute is the price history of the stock. When I query a stock, I will always know a start and end date (index of my array), which will usually be a very small subset of the entire array, so I'd optimally like to return my item with just that subset filled in the array attribute.

I guess a more standard way of doing this would be to use a relational database instead with a "prices" table, but that wouldn't fit that well with the rest of my model, while also ending up in being a table with an absolute humongous amount of entries.

Really, what I'm trying to do is just reduce the cost of my AWS calls.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the question asks how to a return a subset of a single attribute value (which is unsupported in DynamoDB) rather than how to return a subset of available attributes (which *is* supported). I've answered the latter.

You haven't indicated which language SDK you are using, but all SDKs expose the DynamoDB [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) API call and they all allow you to indicate which attributes you want returned to you in [ProjectionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ProjectionExpression) or the legacy AttributesToGet.

An example ProjectionExpression is "Artist, Genre" for the two named attributes.

Comment: Yes, but that gets me the whole attribute. I don't want a subset of _attributes_ , I want a subset of the values of _an attribute_. Refer to my example: If I have an array of stock prices as an attribute, I might want to just return a subset of that price history with my item.

Comment: OK, I see that I mis-read the original question. DynamoDB doesn't support that. I'm not actually sure that *any* database supports that type of access. How would you indicate which indices of the attribute/column value array you wanted to retrieve, for example?

Comment: I mean, I *could* give a start and end index. But yeah, I guessed as much. The problem is that my items get quite close to the 40KB record limit due to it which would cost, like, 10 read-costs instead of 1, when really I always just need a subset small enough to query it in 1-3 read-costs.

Comment: If you know the query patterns in advance, can you split the single item into multiple items, each containing some subset of the attribute values, perhaps partitioned by date/time in some way, for example? I'm not sure what the embedded data is, but in the stock data analogy, you might actually have one item per stock ticker symbol per day, where that item included the opening and closing price, for example, and could potentially include hourly prices in an array attribute.